# Synchronize git repository with server without git

Tags: git, synchronization

I am currently a newbie with git.

My idea is, that I am working with my local git repo and push this to a bare repo.

But then I want to publish the changes to a live site, which has no possibility to install git. So I am not able to do a pull on the live site from the bare repo. 
How would you sync the changes from a bare git repository to this live site?

Thank you very much for your ideas.

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't install anything on the remote server, you would write a deployment script that would "publish" the code *to* the site using ssh (rsync), sftp, or other file transfer method.  I would not include any login information in the script, rather require it as either a parameter to the script or an environment variable.

Here's a _*simple*_ example using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "deploy usage:
    echo "   deploy sshtarget # uses rsync"

    exit 1
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    usage
fi

echo "Deploying to $1..."

rsync -e ssh -avh --progress --exclude .git* --exclude .giti* --exclude deploy * $1

exit 0
```

So this uses the user's current ssh identity as the basis for copying the files to the remote server and "sshtarget" would be the remote directory.  For example if the `deploy` script was at the root of the source tree and so were the files you'd publish:

```
./deploy username@server.com:/var/www/folder
```

Again, a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) which might be especially suitable for website deployment as FTP is usually available.